# Agents -or and -ant in the same sentence

Tags: agent-noun-suffix

The suffices *-or* and *-ant* each identify agents.  For example, *inquisitor; disputant.*

Question: where two agents, each with a distinct role, are in play, can or should one use both *-or* and *-ant* in the same sentence?

Example:

> It has been fashionable to impute such sentiments to fanaticism.  Fashion, however, is as fleeting as it is shallow; and one ought anyway to ask which is the fanatic: the imputant or the imputor?

If wrong, what alternatives?

If right, does *-ant* bear any connotation *-or* lacks?

**DICTIONARY DEFINITIONS**

For reference, Webster 1913 gives these:

- **-or** \-or\ suff. [L. -or: cf. OF. -or, -ur, -our, F. -eur.] ... A noun suffix denoting an agent or doer; as in auditor, one who hears; donor, one who gives; obligor, elevator. It is correlative to -ee. In general -or is appended to words of Latin, and -er to those of English, origin. See {-er}.
- **-ant** \-ant\ [F. -ant, fr. L. -antem or -entem, the pr. p. ending; also sometimes directly from L. -antem.] A suffix sometimes marking the agent for action; as, merchant, covenant, servant, pleasant, etc. Cf. {-ent}.

Comment: If I read this sentence, I would struggle to understand it, but I would guess that the *imputor* was the one who did the imputing, and the *imputant* was the one upon whom the imputing was done. A more familiar pair of prefixes for this are *-er/-ee* (or *-or/-ee*).

Comment: @MikeGraham I had thought of that so I am glad that you have brought it up. Your guess is right, and maybe *-ee* is better, but then I was thinking: what *about* *-or* versus *-ant?* I did not know the answer to the last question, which is why I asked.

Comment: Please give linked and attributed dictionary definitions of both words. Is there a potential conflict in meaning (both seem rare)?  Does 'employers must consider risks to their employees' pose any problems?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Dictionary definitions added (source is offline; cannot link). Regarding *employee,* I had thought that that was a person employed, whereas my *imputant* is not a person imputed as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, but (good though these are) I meant for 'imputant & 'imputor'. You need to give the definitions for each (and, if there are several senses, you need to point out the default sense, mentioned first in most dictionaries).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The words *imputant* and *imputor* do not appear in my dictionary. They are constructs. The word *imputer* appears but I did not use it because the Saxon *-er* does not seem to harmonize with the Latinate *-ant.* Anyway, my question regards *-or* and *-ant* together in the same sentence, not *impute,* especially. The imputant was just an example.

Comment: Examples need to use English, not DIY non-words. As does sensible communication in everyday English. Using contrivances makes the question nebulous, perhaps nonsensical. Certainly off-topic. With a real example, 'Employers must consider risks to their employees' shows that there is no reason at all not to use agent and 'recipient/subjected' variants of a base word in the same sentence where sensible.

Comment: There are many high quality, free online dictionaries you can use as references and link to. The [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question cannot be answered in general terms along the lines of "is -ant or -or right?". It depends very much on the conventionalised use of Latinates of either suffix for specific words.